# Predict the revenue

Tags: r, prediction, data-science

I'm sorry for posting this simple question, but I'm only crawling in the world of predictive analytics. I've got monthly revenue for period Dec15-Apr16. I realize that a sample is quite small, but unfortunately that is all i need to deal with. 
I tried using Solver in excel but it doesn't seem to be quite accurate. I tried to use time series and HoltWinters in R too, but it seems like i need to have 24 periods so it seems like i cannot use this method neither. Would you please help me figure out how to predict value for May( ignoring seasonality, constraints etc)?

```
           Revenue

   Dec-15   2035
   Jan-16   2115
   Feb-16   2625
   Mar-16   2570
   Apr-16   2170
```

Comment: Simple linear regression model will do here .

Comment: Given the small number of data points you'd just take the average

Comment: Thanks guys, i'll do both and see what fits better.

Answer (score 0):

Given the very few data you have I don't think you need any advanced thinking on this. You could simply take the average of all (or some, the last 2,3,4 ...) months, or use linear regression (check function `lm()`)

Comment: Thanks Clemk, i thought there would be more 'sophisticated' approach to this, but i'll give linear regression a go.